# HTML and c# how to bind label value to marque

Tags: c#, html

How to pass the values which i have in label.text to the marque .can any one give me a idea..

Comment: What does this mean? Your question is very unclear. Can you give us an example? What is a marque?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may achieve this in this fashion

Assign the label text to a literal in this way

```
  literal.Text = string.Format("<marquee>{0} </marquee>", lbl.Text);
```

OR

Show it in the label

```
lbl.Text = string.Format("<marquee>{0} </marquee>", "Hello Scrolling text");
```

Comment: If this worked then remember to mark it as answer, this will help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

In you page create a public property

```
public string MarqueText { get; set; }
```

Populate the property in Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MarqueText = "The text to display in marque, very long long text e.t.c";
}
```

Then use the property in your aspx page by asp.net code block.

```
<marquee scrollamount="3"><%= MarqueText %></marquee>
```

Comment: The `<marquee>` tag went out of style back in 1993. Using it now just makes your webpage look like a joke.

Comment: @Cody, Thanks but its not my problem, you can suggest it the questioner.

Comment: @Cody, have a look; **HTML and c# how to bind label value to marque???** so I suggest how to pass value inside marquee.